# What is the meaning of sign + in front of a lambda?

Tags: c++, lambda, closures, function-pointers, standards

```
int main()
{
    void(*fp1)() =  []{}; // ok
    void(*fp2)() = +[]{}; // also ok
}
```

I cannot find any explanation in [cppreference.com](http://cppreference.com) on the meaning of sign + in front of the lambda.

What is the exact meaning of sign + here as per the C++ standard?